# Jest Mock changes to undefined from one line to another

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, aws-lambda, jestjs

I want to test my AWS Lambda functions written in typescript. The problem is that I'm mocking a service, which initially works fine and has all expected functions, but from one line to the other it turns to `undefined`, even though in the console.log right before it is defined.

My lambda function:

```
export const changePassword = LambdaUtils.wrapApiHandler(
async (event: LambdaUtils.APIGatewayProxyEvent, context: Context) => {

    const accessToken = event?.body?.accessToken;
    const previousPassword = event?.body?.previousPassword;
    const proposedPassword = event?.body?.proposedPassword;

    // let authenticationService = Injector.getByName("AuthenticationService"); // I tried mocking this object but given the dependency injection it is always undefined

    //Request
    const authenticationService = new AuthenticationService(); // Here it is perfectly mocked
    console.log("-> authenticationService", authenticationService); // Here it is also defined with all functions
    const response = await authenticationService.changePassword( 
        accessToken,
        previousPassword,
        proposedPassword
    ); //Here authenticationService is undefined

    console.log("response in auth_handler", response);

    
    if (response?.statusCode === 200) {
        return new LambdaUtilities().createHttp200Response(response);
    } 
}
```

);

My test component:

```
jest.mock("../../../controllers/auth.service");
const MockedAuthService = AuthenticationService as jest.Mock<AuthenticationService>;

.....

  test(`Test successful response of changePassword Repo function"`, async () => {
    const accessToken = "accessToken";
    const previousPassword = "123456";
    const proposedPassword = "654321";

    const mockAuthService = new MockedAuthService() as jest.Mocked<AuthenticationService>;
    console.log("-> mockAuthService", mockAuthService);

    const event = {
        body: {
            accessToken,
            proposedPassword,
            previousPassword
        }
    };
    const response = await changePassword(event, {}, {});

    console.log("response", response);
    expect(response).not.toBeNull();
});
```

Here are screenshots from a debug with PyCharm:
[image: Here the authenticationService is still defined]
[image: Here it appears to be undefined]